# Texturing a Quad in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017, sfml

So far I've learned how to create a cube with textures in OpenGL.
Now I want to change this code for texturing a Quad. I've changed the vertices + indices from a cube to a quad.

And the Quad looks like this:

[image]

The texture is completely distorted and the upper triangle is missing...

This is the code I'm using:

1.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,  
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,  
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f
};

unsigned int indices[]{
    0,1,2,
    1,2,3,
};
```

2.

```
for (size_t o = 0; o < 6; o++) {
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, breite_komplett);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, ausschnitt_x_counter);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, ausschnitt_y_counter);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + o, 0, GL_RGBA, ausschnitt_breite, ausschnitt_höhe, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sprite_image.getPixelsPtr());
}
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Do you have an ideas what I need to change?

---

Edit:

```cpp
unsigned int indices[]{
    0,1,2,
    0,2,3
};
```

[image]

This is my object builder:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &obj_vao);
glBindVertexArray(obj_vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &obj_ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indicies[0])* indicies_count, indicies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &obj_vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices[0]) * count_vertices, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertices[0]) * 5, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertices[0]) * 5, (void*)(sizeof(vertices[0]) * 3));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

---

Edit:

If the vertices would be like this:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Everything would be fine and the Quad looks like this:
[image]

But I need the Quad in the origin like this:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

With this vertices the texture is distorted...

Comment: *"With this vertices the texture is distorted"* of course it is. Because the texture coordinate for the cubmap texture is a direction vector! Eiter create a 2 dimensional texture or create separate 3 dimensional texture coordinates for the cubemap texture. Anyway if you want to form a cube with 6 sides, then you have to change the vertex coordinates.

Comment: No, my earlier code was a cube with 6 sides and a cubemap-texture. Now I want to change the code to a 2D-Quad with texture

Comment: at the moment i have just one square image. And this image is used for every side of the cube. When you look at the for-loop, there's always the same image which is added to the cubemap

Comment: Sorry, I think the question should be: How to change a cubemap-texture to a 2D-texture :D

Comment: That depends on. Do you know how to change the shader program? For using a simple 2d texture I recommend to read [LearnOpenGL - Textures](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indices of the 2 triangle primitives do not form a quad. The indices have to be:

<s>`unsigned int indices[]{ 0, 1, 2,   1, 2, 3 };`</s>

```cpp
unsigned int indices[]{ 0, 1, 2,   0, 2, 3 };
```

```
3          0
 +-----+  +
 |   /  / |
 | /  /   |
 +  +-----+
2          1
```

---

When you crate the texture, the you mix `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` and `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. That makes no sense. Either create a cubemap texture and set the parameters for the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` or create a 2 dimensional texture.

---

Anyway if you want to create a cubemap texture, then you have to use `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, when you set the parameters, too.

The texture coordinate for a texture cube is a 3 dimensional vector. Change the vertex coordinates for the side of the cube. e.g:
(You don't need the texture coordinates at all)

```cpp
GLfloat vertices[] = {
//   x      y      z     
     1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 
     1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,  
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,  
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

The center of the cube is (0, 0, 0), so you can use the vertex coordinates for the texture, too:

Vertex shader

```c
in vec3 position;

out vec3 cubeCoord;

void main()
{
    cubeCoord = position;

    // [...]
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
in vec3 cubeCoord;
uniform samplerCube cubeTex;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture(cubeTex, cubeCoord);

    // [...]
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use separate 3 dimensional texture coordinates for the cubemap texture:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
//   x      y      z       u      v      w
     1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,   1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,   1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the Problem with the missing Rectangle! But the texture is disorted anyway...

Comment: Sorry @Rabbid76, I'm a newbie. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I need the Quad to center at (0/0/0) so I can rotate the Quad at it's origin

Comment: Do you know how to change the cubemap texture to a normal 2 dimension texture for the Quad?